# has many through association rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Users can upload tracks and create playlist. I have a model for playlist and i have a model for playlist_track which is for users that can save to the playlist. I can create a new playlist but how do i add the tracks to the playlist in the views?

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2018_12_06_050857) do

  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "active_storage_attachments", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name", null: false
    t.string "record_type", null: false
    t.bigint "record_id", null: false
    t.bigint "blob_id", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.index ["blob_id"], name: "index_active_storage_attachments_on_blob_id"
    t.index ["record_type", "record_id", "name", "blob_id"], name: "index_active_storage_attachments_uniqueness", unique: true
  end

  create_table "active_storage_blobs", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "key", null: false
    t.string "filename", null: false
    t.string "content_type"
    t.text "metadata"
    t.bigint "byte_size", null: false
    t.string "checksum", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.index ["key"], name: "index_active_storage_blobs_on_key", unique: true
  end

  create_table "playlist_tracks", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "playlist_id"
    t.integer "track_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "playlists", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "plays", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.integer "track_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "tracks", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "genre"
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.string "name"
    t.date "release_date"
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "username"
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
  end

  add_foreign_key "active_storage_attachments", "active_storage_blobs", column: "blob_id"
end
```

Here is my track model

```
class Track < ApplicationRecord
    has_many_attached :mp3

    belongs_to :user, optional: true
    has_many :playlist_tracks
    has_many :playlists, through: :playlist_tracks
    has_many :plays
end
```

and here is my playist_track model

```
class PlaylistTrack < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :playlist
  belongs_to :track
end
```

Comment: How do you want to add them? With a select/multi-select field, or with checkboxes, or with some kind of a search field? Try to implement first version of the form, and we can help you with particular problems

Comment: Well the way i want to do it when users are going through all different sort of tracks they have options on each track to add to the playlist

Comment: `Add` button to the right of each track, on click it opens select with user's playlists. It should be a remote form which creates PlaylistTrack instance with AJAX - you know both ids, track and playlist